# MS Project 2019 (or lower) scheduling algorithm

Tags: ms-project, scheduling

Whats resource constrained scheduling algorithm is used by MS Project 2019? What RCPSP algorithm is behind a so called a resources leveling in MS Project 2019?

Comment: I posted it here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76137154/ms-project-2019-scheduling-algorithm?noredirect=1#comment134433282_76137154